# Parent click events overlaps children click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to click the parent div, but have the child form and anchor elements be exempt from the click event.

```
<div class="root">

    <div class="parent">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="/blah"> Hello World</a>
            <div>
                <span> Hello World Again
            </div>
            <form class="form">
                <label> inputs
                <input id="text" type="text"/>
                <textarea></textarea>
                <input id="submit" type="submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".parent").on("click", ".container", function() {
    alert("Parent clicked");
});

$(".parent").on("click", "#text", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Form Input clicked");
});

$(".parent").on("click", "#submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Form Button clicked");
});

 $(".parent").on("click", "a", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("anchor link clicked");
});
```

Clicking on any of the form elements (input, textarea, button submit) or the anchor tag won't work because the parent click event is firing.

How can I make the parent click event only on elements outside of the child form and anchor tag? The parent click event can cover any of the other children except those two elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Hook the `click` event on the relevant child container (it looks like it would be the form) and use `event.stopPropagation()` within the handler. That will stop the event bubbling to the parent. Something like this:

   ```
   // Option 1: Hook on the form and stop
   // propagation (hooking up "false" does an
   // implicit preventDefault + stopPropagation)
   $(".parent").on("click", "form", false);
   ```
2. Inside the parent's handler, check to see if the parent element is the element that was the *source* of the event (`e.target`). If it is, process the event; if it isn't, ignore it, it was generated on a child element. Something like this:

   ```
   $(".parent").on("click", ".container", function(event) {
       // Option 2: Look at event.target and ignore
       // the event if it originated in a descendant
       // element
       if (this === event.target) {
           alert("Parent clicked");
       }
   });
   ```

Note that those do two slightly different things. The first one says "Prevent the parent from seeing clicks on the form" whereas the second one says "Ignore clicks that aren't directly on `.parent .container`". Either can be adapted, of course, with different targeting.

Live Examples:

- [Your original problem](http://jsbin.com/yoyanolu/1)
- [Option 1](http://jsbin.com/yoyanolu/2)
- [Option 2](http://jsbin.com/yoyanolu/3)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the closing anchor tag. I've edited my post to include it.

Comment: @user21398: Ah! That explains it. I should have looked more closely.

Comment: The second method doesn't seem to fit my scenario mainly because I want the other children to be covered by the parent's click. So the `Hello World Again` div/span should be affected by the parent's click whereas the anchor and form should not. The first method works, but then it seems to prevent anything else inside the form from being clicked. ie, the submit button doesn't fire its own click handler, which is a big problem.

Comment: @user21398: It doesn't in [my example above](http://jsbin.com/yoyanolu/2), clicking the submit button works just fine. It's tricky because all of your handlers are delegated, but I checked to see if the order in which they were hooked up was an issue, and [it didn't seem to matter](http://jsbin.com/yoyanolu/4).

Comment: @user21398: The second option can be adapted (as I noted above) to various scenarios. For instance, suppose you want to ignore clicks on only specific elements: `if ($(event.target).closest("#text, #submit, .container").hasClass("container")) {` ([example](http://jsbin.com/yoyanolu/5)). That would allow clicks on things inside `.container` provided they weren't `#text` or `#submit`:

Comment: Just tried the second method too and it seems like a more flexible approach. Good to know!